# Alternative to deprecated method ObjectMapper.reader(Class)

Tags: java, jackson

I am developing a JSON parsing application and want to use `ObjectReader`.

I get my instance of object reader as follows -

```
private static final ObjectMapper OBJECT_MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();
private static final ObjectReader OBJECT_READER = OBJECT_MAPPER.reader(MyType.class);
```

however the `OBJECT_MAPPER.reader(MyType.class);` is showing as deprecated.

What alternative do I have to obtain an `ObjectReader`?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

[`ObjectMapper.reader(Class)`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#reader-java.lang.Class-) was deprecated since Jackson 2.5.

Starting with Jackson 2.6, you can use [`readerFor(Class)`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#readerFor-java.lang.Class-) instead.

Comment: Hi, do you know if there were any functional differences between `reader` and `readerFor`? I'm guessing there must be some because otherwise `reader` would just have been updated...

Comment: Ok, I looked at the source - they are exactly the same, and safe to switch